# "column does not exist" for SELECT ST_Point

Tags: postgis

I am using psql (9.5.2) and postgis 2.2.2. In the psql shell,
I have created a spatial database and connected to it.  I want to insert a point into the postgis geodatabase.

To do so, I first create a table in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( 
  p_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

);
```

Then I want to create a point using:

```
select st_point(­101, 20);
```

However, I got an error:

```
ERROR:  column "­101" does not exist
```

What is the reason of this error?

Comment: Is PostGIS installed, check with `select postgis_version()`. For some reason, if I copy-paste your SQL I am getting the same error but if I write the text from the keyboard the query is successful.

Comment: Have you tried `ST_Point`? Commands might be case-sensitive.

Comment: That really works. The prompt returned "st_point                  
--------------------------------------------
 010100000000000000004059400000000000003440
(1 row)". But I was expecting the st_point function to return the coordinate values. Do you have the same return result?

Comment: Hi AndreJ, I tried ST_Point, it return the same thing with the st_point.

Comment: It gives error too for me if I copy paste.  it's the -- is not really a minus coming thru.  I had to replace the -- with a - and then it worked.

Comment: @LR1234567, thanks, that sounds the source of the error. Could you speciify which command would have an extra minus sign?

Comment: I don't know PostGIS at all, but is `(101, 20)` Lat/Long?  If so the 101 wouldn't be a valid Lat value.  If not then ignore me

Comment: The default return value is a hexadecimal dump of the binary object.  You need to use `ST_AsText(geomcol)` to get Well-Known Text.

Answer (score 1):

You have a hidden [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) character before 101, e.g. copy & paste into a Python shell shows me:

```
select st_point(\xc2\xad101, 20);
```

Retype this SQL statement using ASCII characters, and it should work.